# Android Greendao 1:N relationships

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I have two entities that I'm trying to relate and although I'm retrieving the entities from the server properly with the relationships, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

I have two Entities: `Account` and `Song`

Where one `Account` can have many `Song` and one `Song` can only belong to one `Account`

In my generation file, I have done the following:

```
Entity account = schema.addEntity("Account");
account.addLongProperty("id").primaryKey().notNull().getProperty();
Property accountId = account.addLongProperty("accountId").getProperty();
account.addStringProperty("name");
account.addStringProperty("comments");

Entity song = schema.addEntity("Song");
song.addLongProperty("id").primaryKey().notNull().getProperty();
Property songId = song.addLongProperty("songId").getProperty();
song.addStringProperty("name");
song.addStringProperty("artist");

ToMany accountToSongs = account.addToMany(song, accountId);
accountToSongs.setName("songs");
song.addToOne(account, songId);
```

When I make an HTTP call to the server, I'm able to do a `account.getSongs()` and see that the relationship is there, but I know these aren't persisted when you do an `insert` into sqlite.

Now I need to access all the songs of a given `id` of the `Account` model but I'm not quite sure if I'm missing a step or if I generated the files incorrectly. Am I supposed to manually set the `songs` to each `account`? Are my properties in the file generation incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by changing how my file generation project was constructed.

I did the following instead:

```
Entity account = schema.addEntity("Account");
account.addLongProperty("id").primaryKey().notNull().getProperty();
Property accountId = account.addLongProperty("accountId").getProperty();
account.addStringProperty("name");
account.addStringProperty("comments");

Entity song = schema.addEntity("Song");
song.addLongProperty("id").primaryKey().notNull().getProperty();
Property accountId = song.addLongProperty("accountId").getProperty();
song.addStringProperty("name");
song.addStringProperty("artist");

ToMany songToAccounts = account.addToMany(song, accountId);
songToAccounts.setName("songs");
song.addToOne(account, accountId);
```

I was pretty much doing the opposite when creating the properties of my foreign entities. I was a bit confused with the wording but generally, this way works. Just make sure that you know that the Foreign entities are NOT persisted when you persist the parent element.